# Getting strange error while trying to set up an iterator

Tags: c++

This is probably a silly error but I can't seem to find what I have done wrong.

The error I am getting is `no operator "=" matches these operands`.

Here is my code...

```
void print_words(const map < string, int >& m1) {
map<string, int>::iterator it;
cout << "Number of non-empty words: " << m1.size() << '\n';

int count = 0;
for (it = m1.begin(); it != m1.end(); it++) {

    }
}
```

I get the error in the for loop in the `it = m1.begin()` statement and I cannot go on to print out the map if I can't iterate through it.

Comment: also i set up an iterator in another method and it worked fine so i really dont know whats wrong with this method.

Comment: The type of `m1.begin()` is `map<string, int>::const_iterator`, what with `m1` being `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a const iterator:

```
void print_words(const map < string, int >& m1) {
    cout << "Number of non-empty words: " << m1.size() << '\n';
    int count = 0;
    for (map<string, int>::const_iterator it = m1.cbegin(); it != m1.cend(); it++) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `const_iterator` or `auto`.

```
void print_words(const map < string, int >& m1) {
    cout << "Number of non-empty words: " << m1.size() << '\n';
    int count = 0;
    for (auto it = m1.cbegin(); it != m1.cend(); it++) {
    }
}
```